# React js: initialize ZURB Foundation JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am developing a web application with React and Foundation.

Foundation js is initialized by adding `$(document).foundation();`.

Any idea how I can initialize my react application with foundation js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that worked for me is initialize foundation using `componentDidMount()` function.

```
class RSAccordion extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      $(document).foundation()
    }
    render() {
      return (
          //     Your
          //     HTML
          //     Here
      )
    }
  }
```

This way foundation js is initialized every time the code is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Using the (jQuery based) Foundation JavaScript can lead to a lot of issues.

It's commonly easy to use libraries like [react-foundation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-foundation).